# How to show all the elements of an array in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an array like this: `var array = ["Chinese", "Italian", "Japanese", "French", "American"]`

I want to print out all separate elements on a new line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can simply ***iterate through the array*** like this and print out all elements on a new line:

```
for element in array {
  println(element)
}
```

**UPDATE**

For Swift 2 and Swift 3:

```
for element in array {
  print(element)
}
```

Or if you want it on the same line:

```
for element in array {
  print(element, terminator: " ")
}
```

Answer (score 113):

My personal favorite for debugging purposes is dump() which also prints which index the element has. Perfect if you have arrays within an array too.

```
var array = ["Chinese", "Italian", "Japanese", "French", "American"]
dump(array)
```

This will generate the following output

```
▿ 5 elements
  - [0]: Chinese
  - [1]: Italian
  - [2]: Japanese
  - [3]: French
  - [4]: American
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Comment: imho dump is great in UI testing to easily see a list of child buttons, for example...

Answer (score 29):

#### Update:

Starting in iOS 9 you can now just use `dump`

```
var someArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
dump(someArray)
```

#### Original:

This is a nice way to print arrays:

```
var someArray = ["one", "two", "three"]

// prints out the elements separated by a line break
// same as calling "println" on each item in the array:
println(someArray.joinWithSeparator("\n"))

// one
// two
// three
```

Otherwise if you want them on the same line you can just simply print the array:

```
// prints on the same line:
// ["one", "two", "three"]
println(someArray)
```

Answer (score 5):

NB if you don't like the formatting of `dump(…)`, then you can see from its signature that it has some defaulted parameters, thus will allow for some customization.

Having said that, there are two more alternatives to consider that might provide more flexibility—*for you to decide whether or not at the expense of readability!*

First off, if you like closure argument notation, e.g. shorthand argument names, and/or you would like to first manipulate your array before you print it, you can use `forEach`:

```
array.forEach() { print($0) }
Chinese
Italian
Japanese
French
American

array.sorted(by: {$1 > $0}).forEach() { print($0) }
American
Chinese
French
Italian
Japanese
```

Secondly, if you want an index but `dump(…)` is a bit too verbose, try:

```
for (n, nationality) in array.enumerated() { print("\(n) \(nationality)") }
0 Chinese
1 Italian
2 Japanese
3 French
4 America
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also print the array as a string representation using `println(arrayName.description)`